# how can i use MediaPlayer at android 7.0?

Tags: android, audio, streaming

I need straming audio file in my project.

I try this code, it works at android 5.0 but dosen't work at 7.0.

```
    String url = "http://sites.google.com/site/ubiaccessmobile/sample_audio.amr";

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    mediaPlayer.start();
```

mediaPlayer.prepare() throw error 
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

if i use audio file in resource, this code perfectly work.
but for streaming didn't.

i try prepareAsync(), prepare() in another thread. but same error exist.
of course, i use try-catch.

i think for runtime permisson, but this app need only INTERNET. and it didn't need runtime permisson.

what can i do??
android 7.0 cant use streaming audio???

please tell me problem, or another library.

I solve it....?
I cant know what the hell is it, if i use another audio format - like mp3, m4a - this code perfectly work.
why android 7.0 hate amr file???

Comment: I think that you have not set up the Runtime Permission which is introduced from Android 6.0. Hope that helps!

Comment: i think permisson, too.
but what permisson?? i think this app need just INTERNET permisson, it didn't need runtime permisson, didnt it?

Comment: "Runtime Permission" is the way to set/enable permission started from Android 6.0. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i read it. but "INTERNET" permisson is not 'dangerous' permisson, than it didn't need runtime. isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch for *mediaPlayer.prepare()* as:

```
try { 
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```